# Regex replacement with a hex to rgba() conversion

Tags: php, regex

The function below takes an input filestream and replaces the $color values with stored values from a database (color1=ffffff, color2=aaaaaa, color3=cccccc, etc)

Currently it only does a straight find/replace on 6 digit hex values. Is there a regex I can add to the my_colorReplace functon in order to return either a 6 digit hex or a 9 digit rgb based on the input stream pattern?

```
function my_colorReplace($buffer) {

 /* NEED REGEX HERE TO DETERMINE WHETHER TO CALL CONVERTHEXTORGB() */

    $buffer = str_replace(array('$color1'), '#'.get_option("my_theme_header_color").'', $buffer);
    $buffer = str_replace(array('$color2'), '#'.get_option("my_theme_sidebar_color").'', $buffer);
    $buffer = str_replace(array('$color3'), '#'.get_option("my_theme_spot_color_alt").'', $buffer);
    $buffer = str_replace(array('$color4'), '#'.get_option("my_theme_spot_color_alt2").'', $buffer);
return $buffer;
}
```

Utility function to convert a hex value to rgb

```
function convertHexToRGB($hexColor){
    if( preg_match( '/^#?([a-h0-9]{2})([a-h0-9]{2})([a-h0-9]{2})$/i', $hexColor, $matches ) )
    {
    return array('red' => hexdec( $matches[1] ),'green' => hexdec( $matches[2] ),'blue' => hexdec( $matches[3] ));
    }
    else
    {
        return array( 120, 120, 120 );
    }
}
```

Input stream ($buffer):

```
.sidebar{
    background:$color1;
    color:$color2;
    }

.header{
    background: 
        linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba($color1,.5) 0%, 
        rgba(255,255,255,0.96) 100px, 
        rgba(255,255,255,0.95) 150px); /* W3C */

    color:rgb($color3); 
}
```

Expected output of $buffer return (where color1=ffffff, color2=aaaaaa, color3=cccccc

```
.sidebar{
    background:#fffff;
    color:#aaaaaa;
    }

.header{
    background: 
        linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,.5) 0%, 
        rgba(255,255,255,0.96) 100px, 
        rgba(255,255,255,0.95) 150px); /* W3C */

    color:rgb(204,204,204); 
}
```

Comment: I'm ok with the hex-to-rgb conversion. I'm more interested in the regex bits to parse out the input file values to determine whether to do straight replacement or convert and replace.

Comment: I see some variables which i don't know the values of it, i think The story about the database and wordpress functions are just an extra, could you please narrow or summarize the problem down to for example "I want to convert this `rgba(255,255,255,0.96)` to `ffffff` with regex", maybe this will be more clear for us ?

Comment: The variables are just static color values stored in the db. I've updated the question with a comment where I'm looking for help. Basically need to run a regex on the $buffer stream to determine if the element is rgb or rgba. If so, call convert function, if not, send to str_replace.

Comment: Quick question: _why_ would you replace a variable 2 times? Why not: `str_replace('$color1', convertHexToRGB('#'.get_option("my_theme_header_color")), $buffer)`?

Comment: I could be overthinking it. But your example should work and just require all values to be converted to rgb. Go ahead and add it as an answer if you will.

Comment: Why not do a find/replace on `rgb($color1)`, `rgb($color2)`, etc... then a find/replace on `$color1`, `$color2`, etc? If it's meant to become 9 digit it becomes 9 digit because that replacement runs first, else it becomes 6 digit. Alternatively, you could use a regex like `(rgb\()?($color1)(\))?`, and now the optional `rgb()` is captured - if it's then in the regex's capture, so 9 digit conversion, else do 6 digit conversion.

Comment: +1 Patashu, I follow your logic but can't put it together yet. Add the regex as an answer inside the my_colorReplace() function and I'll give it a shot.